# Override 204 status code message

Tags: ruby, xml, json, http, http-status-code-404

When we get a no content response as 204, it comes with a message "No Content" and displays a response

```
      Response : #<Net::HTTPNoContent 204 No Content  readbody=true>
```

while i want the response like :

```
 <response>
   <request_id>4ccf18f0-e83d-012e-29f7-042b2b8686e6</request_id>
   <status_code>204</status_code>
   <message>No Offers were found</message>
</response>
```

Can i override the default message of 204 error.The method which is being called to create the response.

```
def generate_success_response_without_data(format, request_id, message)
  status_code = 204
  format_type_method, options_hash, content_type = get_format_method(format)
  data = {
    "request_id" => request_id,
    "status_code" => status_code,
    "message" => message
  }
  data = generate_data_format(format, data)
  resp = [status_code, {"Content-Type" => content_type}, data.send(format_type_method, options_hash)]
  # Convert rack response to action controller response           
  generate_active_controller_response_format(resp)
  resp
end
```

EDIT:
As stated in http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.

Can we hack somehow and show a message body

Comment: I am not sure if hacking will help, most of the clients will not expect any message body when receiving 204 response, they will just ignore it (although I am not sure about this).

Comment: @Ernest ..yaa i agree with you but the in my case they expect and that's what has laid me here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP 204 is NOT error response. 204 is used when response was successful and content body is *intentionally empty*.

From: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

> The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an
>   entity-body, and might want to return updated metainformation. The
>   response MAY include new or updated metainformation in the form of
>   entity-headers, which if present SHOULD be associated with the
>   requested variant.
>
> If the client is a user agent, it SHOULD NOT change its document view
>   from that which caused the request to be sent. This response is
>   primarily intended to allow input for actions to take place without
>   causing a change to the user agent's active document view, although
>   any new or updated metainformation SHOULD be applied to the document
>   currently in the user agent's active view.
>
> The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is always
>   terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.

In this particular situation, 404 looks like more suitable.

More here: http://benramsey.com/archives/http-status-204-no-content-and-205-reset-content/